# cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

Tags: java, android, firebase

I downloaded a project from GitHub to modify but found some errors

This project can be opened directly but will use the author's firebase

i updated
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
core: 20.0.2
storage:20.0.0
auth:21.0.1
messaging: 23.0.0

After that, it was found that error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

After I searched online, I found that FirebaseInstanceIdService is no longer in use, changed to FirebaseMessagingService, but in the project, I found the file FirebaseMessagingService.java

In the end, I deleted the error place directly, but finally this problem appeared Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > java

This is MyFirebaseInstaceIdService.java

```
package com.example.cr7.mobieshop;

import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class MyFirebaseInstaceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        final String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        Pref sharedPrefrenceHelper=new Pref(getApplicationContext());
        sharedPrefrenceHelper.saveFCMId(refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

This is category_class.java

```
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    upload = new upload_userdata();
                    upload.setUser_name(ds.getValue(upload_userdata.class).getUser_name());
                    upload.setProfile_pic_url(ds.getValue(upload_userdata.class).getProfile_pic_url());
                    namee = upload.getUser_name();
                    img_str = upload.getProfile_pic_url();
                }
            }

            tvName.setText(namee);
            Picasso.get().load(img_str).into(imgProfile);

            final String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendRegistrationToServer(token,namee);
                }
            }, 10000);

        }
```

this is build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'hawkx'
            keyPassword 'asdfghjkl'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/VINAY/Desktop/release/app-release.apk')
            storePassword 'asdfghjkl'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cr7.mobieshop"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Have you tried to update the dependencies to the latest versions?

Comment: I updated firebase and it was originally
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
firebase-core:16.0.3'
firebase-storage:16.0.1'
firebase-storage:16.0.1'

Comment: Does it work with the latest versions?

Comment: Probably not as this is a project from 2 years ago

Answer (score 6):

It's depreciated. Here is the new code i use for refreshed tokens from Firebase.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    if(task.isComplete()){
                      String token = task.getResult();


                    }
                }
            });
```

As for 'app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' This issue comes from 2 things:

1. compile sdk version which is not compatible with the new version of dependencies you are using ,so make it atleast 30.

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 30
   buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
   defaultConfig {
   targetSdkVersion 30
   }
   }
2. Add ' multiDexEnabled true' in default config of build.gradle(Module:app) like this.

android {
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
}

Comment: The problem with firebase may be solved, but it appeared * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
About this problem, I looked online and found that the solution is a bit complicated, can anyone help me?
The following is the download address of the github project
https://github.com/vinaylamba9/mobieShop

Comment: This issue comes from 2 things.
1.) compile sdk version which is not compatible with the new version of dependencies you are using so make it atleast 30.
2.) add  ' multiDexEnabled true' in default config of build.gradle(Module:app)

Comment: I updated multiDexEnabled true implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' and android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" , but I still have the same problem, and I updated compileSdkVersion 30 and targetSdkVersion 30 , but implementation support-v4:28.0.0-rc01' test:runner:1.0.2' cardview-v7:28.0.0' recyclerview-v7:28.0.0' design:28.0.0' percent:28.0.0' error occurred

Comment: I may have fixed the problem, but in the new error, error: local variable token is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                                     sendRegistrationToServer(token,namee);

Comment: Its the import that is bad not the code..